# QuartzCore Not Animating?

Tags: ios, objective-c, quartz-2d

I have a View Controller where I have setup a UIImageView and want to animate it with QuartzCore in Xcode - I built the UIImage to live in an Image View that rotates. This rotates fine when I was testing it in it's own project but now that I am pulling it into my current working project it adds the Image View but does not animate? No idea why? Any ideas?

I don't have any errors or Warnings and it's the same code that was working in a separate project? I also have the QuartzCore library added and #imported

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {


    //Setup Image View
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"record01.png"];
    UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
    [imgView setFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height)];
    [imgView setCenter:(CGPoint){160,160}];
    [self.view addSubview:imgView];

    //Animate Image View
    CABasicAnimation *fullRotation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation"];
    fullRotation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0];
    fullRotation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:2 * M_PI];
    fullRotation.duration = 1.5;
    fullRotation.repeatCount = HUGE_VALF;
    [imgView.layer addAnimation:fullRotation forKey:@"fullRotation"];

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

}
```

Console for po [[UIApp keyWindow] recursiveDescription]

```
   |    | <UIImageView: 0x984a9f0; frame = (-6.5 -6.5; 333 333); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x984a040>>
(lldb) po 0x984a040
(int) $2 = 159686720 <CALayer:0x984a040; position = CGPoint (160 160); bounds = CGRect (0 0; 333 333); delegate = <UIImageView: 0x984a9f0; frame = (-6.5 -6.5; 333 333); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x984a040>>; contents = <CGImage 0x9843560>; rasterizationScale = 2; contentsScale = 2>
(lldb)
```

Comment: `[imgView setFrame: (CGRect){{0,0},image.size}];`: this syntax is bad form, but entirely unneeded. `UIImageView` will default to the size of the image. Preferred (but unneeded): `CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height);`)

Comment: Thanks @bshirley - I changed the code to reflect that. Any idea on why it's not animating for me?

Comment: I disagree that using C99 syntax is bad form. In fact I use it exclusively. Maybe it's just a difference of opinion? Why is `CGRectMake` preferred?

Comment: Try rotating just 90 degrees and see if that works. I don't think you can use CABasicAnimation to rotate through 360 degrees easily. You will instead have to use a piecewise animation.. one from -180 to -1 and another from 0 to +180.. or similar (I forget) You will have to experiment

Comment: It has to do with the fact that CABasicAnimation will always choose the shortest difference in angle (mod 360). It will not simply monotonically increase (or decrease) from start to end angle.

Comment: I have 360 working fine on a seperate project where I wrote the code initially. It rotated 360 infinity with this exact code. It just won't rotate when I paste the same code into my working project?

Comment: `CCRectMake` will be more processor change resilience.  This should realistically not be an issue to anyone coding to iOS.  It is more specific about your intent.  It is more resilient to typo errors; when you're casting structs, any accidental errors will be hidden to compiler testing/warnings.

Comment: There is also a macro for `CGPointMake(160, 160)` if you want to use that.  Again, the biggest benefits are clarity of code (to others and to you after you've slept).  And less chance of a hidden syntax issue being hushed by a cast.

Comment: The C99 syntax has exactly as much “processor change resilience” as `CGRectMake`, whatever that means.  What `CGRectMake` buys you is protection against leaving out any initializers (and having the compiler default them to zero).  What `CGRectMake` costs you (in this example) is the need to either call `image.size` twice, or store its return value in a local variable.

Comment: Are you setting `imgView.transform` or `imgView.layer.transform` or `imgView.layer.affineTransform` anywhere else in your code?

Comment: No. The only places I call imgView are in the snippet I've pasted?

Comment: Should I be putting the [imgView.layer addAnimation:fullRotation forKey:@"fullRotation"]; somewhere other than the viewDidLoad perhaps? It's almost like it's just not triggering when I come from my home screen?

Comment: I tried it adding a view and an animation in `viewDidLoad` in a test project and it worked for me.  Something else is going on.  Pause your app in the debugger, run `po [[UIApp keyWindow] recursiveDescription]`, and post the output in your question.

Comment: Ok @robmayoff - I did that and pasted the console in the description above

Comment: Do you see the last line, which is your image view?  It is the one with address `0xfd68a40`.  At the end of the line is a reference to the view's layer (with address `0xfd68400`).  You need to print the description of the layer.  The addresses will be different each time you run your app.  So run it again, pause in the debugger, print the recursive description, and get the address of the image view's layer.  Then print the layer description using the `po` command, like `po 0xfd68400` (but using the new address you get when you run the app again).

Comment: Cool! I updated it for ya @robmayoff - Thoughts?

Comment: If I add - [CATransaction begin]; it starts rotating but then breaks my storyboard transition too for some reason?

Answer (score 0):

I would stay out of `CoreAnimation` if what you can get at in a higher level will do the trick:

```
- (void)spinOnce:(UIView *)view {
  CGAffineTransform rotate = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI * 2);

  [UIView animateWithDuration:1.5
                   animations:^{
                     view.transform = rotate;
                   } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     view.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
                     [self spinOnce:view];
                   }];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {

  //Setup Image View
  UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"record01.png"];
  UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
  [imgView setFrame: (CGRect){{0,0},image.size}];
  [imgView setCenter:(CGPoint){160,160}];
  [self.view addSubview:imgView];

  //Animate Image View      
  [self spinOnce:imgView];

//  CABasicAnimation *fullRotation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation"];
//  fullRotation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0];
//  fullRotation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:((360*M_PI)/180)];
//  fullRotation.duration = 1.5;
//  fullRotation.repeatCount = HUGE_VALF;
//  [imgView.layer addAnimation:fullRotation forKey:@"360"];
//  
//  [super viewDidLoad];
  // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

}
```

Comment: Thanks @bshirley - I have this in there successfully but it still isn't animating? I dunno what could be going wrong? Could it be that I have it showing in a storyboard and I am missing some super simple implementation thing?

Comment: `CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI * 2)` returns the identity matrix.  You shouldn't expect this to do anything.

Comment: (i have not tested this specifically, but have used similar code before), try 359° if 360° isn't working, or even split it in half: Identity/0° to 180°, and 180° to 0°.